# Padding middle of a string

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

I have this requirement to pad strings so that they become 10 characters long.

Example strings :

```
AB..12
ABC...123
```

I need to add dots in the middle of the string (where dots are already present; at least one dot will always be present in the input string) in order to get the total length to 10 characters long:

```
AB......12
ABC....123
```

What would be a good way to accomplish this?

I have come up with this idea, which works, but is really not "nice".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="test1" select="'AB..12'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="dots" select="if(string-length($test1)=9) then '..' 
                                        else if(string-length($test1)=8) then '...' 
                                        else if(string-length($test1)=7) then '....' 
                                        else if(string-length($test1)=6) then '.....' 
                                        else ''"/>
    
    <Result>
      <Test1><xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($test1,'.'),$dots,substring-after($test1,'.'))"/></Test1>
    </Result>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Will all input strings have at least one dot?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Yes they will.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a regular expression you can match the dots and compute the length; the following isn't really very compact but should do the job:

```
  <xsl:param name="separator" as="xs:string" select="'.'"/>
  
  <xsl:param name="pattern" as="xs:string" expand-text="no">^([^.]+)(\.+)([^.]+)$</xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="{$pattern}">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
          <xsl:value-of 
            select="regex-group(1), 
                    (1 to 10 - string-length(regex-group(1)) - string-length(regex-group(3))) ! $separator,
                    regex-group(3)" separator=""/>          
        </xsl:matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

I have assumed you have the string in an element to match on e.g. `item` in above sample, but you could of course stuff the `xsl:analyze-string` into a function instead and call it with any string you have.

Answer (score 2):

Not a pure XSLT 3.0 solution but with the replace-with() function available as a Saxon extension, it's

```
replace-with($input, '\.+', 
  function($s){string-join((1 to 10-string-length($input))!'.')})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for both of your answers. Here's a simple answer I came up with based on your answers.

```
<xsl:variable name="output" select="concat(substring-before($input,'.'),string-join((1 to 10-string-length($input)+1)!'.'),substring-after($input,'.'))"/>
```

So basically take what's before the first dot, add the number of missing dots+1 and then add what's after the first dot.